# How to count rows grouped by an attribute, where that attribute has not appeared before a specific date?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume table Orders

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
order_id int(11),
customer_id int(11),
purchase_date datetime
)
```

We need the following report: For customers who did not place an order prior to this month, how many orders were placed per customer?

Here is the very slow sql that I am currently using:

```
SELECT count(order_id) num_of_orders, customer_id 
FROM   (SELECT order_id, customer_id
        FROM   orders 
        WHERE  customer_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id 
                                   FROM   orders 
                                   WHERE  purchase_date < '2019-03-01')) a 
GROUP  BY customer_id;
```

Is there a faster/more efficient way to write this query?

Comment: `DISTINCT` **is not a function**, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT customer_id ...` to make code clearer. However, DISTINCT isn't even needed here, so a plain SELECT would be fine!

Comment: thanks, fixed @jarlh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would re-write it as :

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id), customer_id
FROM orders o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orders o1 WHERE o1.customer_id = o.customer_id AND o1.purchase_date < '2019-03-01')
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

This will speed up your performance thanks to an index on orders(`customer_id`).

However, if the `orders` table contains `null` for `customer_id`, then `NOT IN` subquery will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will be faster, but it is simpler:

```
SELECT customer_id, count(*) as num_of_orders
FROM  orders o
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MIN(purchase_date) >= '2019-03-01';
```